# How to exclude secondary wrong solution from a linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across the following problem while i was solving a linear first order differential equation:-

$Q.$ Solve: $$y'(xy+y-x-1)=\ln(x+1), y(0)=2$$

My solution is as follows: $$\begin{align}&y'(x+1)(y-1)=\ln(x+1)
\\& \implies y'(y-1)=\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x+1}\\&\implies \int (y-1)dy=\int \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x+1}dx\\&\implies \frac{(y-1)^2}{2}+c=\frac12\ln^2(x+1) \end{align}$$ Now $y(0)=2$, so $c=-\frac12$. This gives the final solution as $$(y-1)^2-1=\ln^2(x+1)$$ But the problem arises that $y(0)=0$ also satisfies this solution. Hence i think, my solution has an unwanted factor. How can I exclude it?

Comment: If you continue you will get $y-1=\pm\sqrt{1+\ln^2(x+1)}$. Do you need solution with plus or with minus sign?

Answer (score 1):

The solution you currently have is not one-to-one. This becomes apparent when you solve for $y$

$$ y(x) = 1 \pm \sqrt{1 + \ln^2 (x+1)}$$

Taking the positive root gives $y(0) = 2$ and the negative root gives $y(0)=0$

Comment: Thank you, is there any way to exclude such solutions from the start?

Comment: In general, the way to pick out the particular solution is to use the initial value. If you didn't have one, both square roots are valid